# extra backslash in the installation path

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, installation-path

I am using VS installer to create an installer for my application. I have a custom action which will pass the installation path to the code behind like the following : `/path="[TARGETDIR]\"`    .
 Inside my installer Class I am displaying the installation path in the Install() method as `path = Context.Parameters["path"]; MessageBox.Show(pathh);`
however, what is displayed is something like this:`c:\Program Files(x86)\Manufacturer\Applicationname\\`
So I don’t know how this extra backslash is added and do not know how to remove it . Any idea?
it is worth mentioning that i was able to creat a file in the installtion path using "pathh"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just want to display the path to the user u can use the following simple trick which works fine in your case: `string path = pathh.Remove(pathh.Length-1);`  `MessageBox.Show(path);`  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making your custom action without the trailing backslash?

Replace

```
/path="[TARGETDIR]\"
```

with

```
/path="[TARGETDIR]"
```

Comment: @alaa what is the actual path you are passing in?

Comment: i have used the following as the default Loction 
[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]
with the property of TARGETDIR